# removed lib modules folder after every reboot

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, netfilter

uname -r: 4.13.0-16-generic (ubuntu 17.10 server)

I have a problem that iptables doesn't work after a reboot:

```
iptables-apply /etc/network/iptables
[ ok ] Stopping fail2ban (via systemctl): fail2ban.service.
Applying new iptables rules from '/etc/network/iptables'... modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic
iptables-restore v1.6.1: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 3
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
failed.
Error: unknown error applying new iptables rules: /etc/network/iptables
Reverting to old iptables rules... done.
```

I've tried to reinstall kernel and iptables:

```
apt install --reinstall linux-generic linux-image-4.13.0-16-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-16-generic linux-headers-4.13.0-16-generic iptables
```

when I reinstall it (without reboot) iptables works after a service restart.

when I reboot the machine I get the same error again.

I've notice that with every reboot the following folder is gone:

```
/lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter
```

only 2 files left in folder ipv4 are:
gre.ko  udp_tunnel.ko

copying the missing files into this location doesn't work, will be removed with the next reboot.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Just wondering, is your root partition an LVM volume? (I'm having the same issue, that `copymods` thing is being mounted and I suspect LVM is the cause of the troubles)

Answer (score 6):

I get the same on Ubuntu 16.04. I don't have a fix, but I have some insight in to why this is happening. During the book process, the system initially boots on a RAM-based file system: initramfs. Later in the boot process, the hard disk takes over, but the modules directory from the initramfs is mounted on the modules directory of the hard disk. Note that the output of `mount` includes the line:

```
copymods on /lib/modules type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
```

Ok, so any changes to /lib/modules, e.g. by executing

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

will be lost when the system is rebooted. So how is this supposed to work? Well, when the `apt install` command adds new modules, it should put a corresponding entry in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks`. Then the  installer script which `apt install` invokes runs `update-initramfs`, which generates the CPIO archive `/boot/initrd.img-(uname -r)` which is your initramfs image, which should now contain the modules needed for iptables to work when the system is rebooted.

The bug is that the relevant entries are never actually made in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks`, and therefor the relevant entries are not made in initramfs, and hence are not preserved when the system is rebooted.

At this point I am stuck.

Comment: In a different variant of this solution, I can also go into `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and manually add the modules I want to have saved into the initramfs images via `update-initramfs`. But it's a bandaid since I can only guess which kernel modules are needed for which program and it's tedious manually updating the image each time a new kernel module is used.

Comment: @xster, this worked for me. thanks! ..at least a temporary fix

Comment: bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1967593

Comment: and actually the two answers below about removing copymods package fixed issues with other modules too.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @scottwh2, the issue is probably that a `copymods` ramfs volume is mounted at `/lib/modules`. To check this, run `mount | grep /lib/modules`.

To remove this, run

```
apt remove cloud-initramfs-copymods
```

Then reboot.

After rebooting, double check that the `copymods` entry is gone from `mount`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu Server 16.04. The command:

```
mount | grep /lib/modules
```

displayed:

```
copymods on /lib/modules type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
```

So firstly I tried to remove cloud-initramfs-copymods, but that package was not installed in my system. Then I've install it:

```
apt-get install cloud-initramfs-copymods
```

And right after that I've remove it:

```
apt-get remove cloud-initramfs-copymods
```

And after rebooting my server copymods is gone and modules are not removed after reboot now! So thanks to **scottwh2** and **falsePockets** I successfully resolved my problem.

Comment: wait, it might have.. after adding my missing module in /etc/initramfs-tools/modules following scottwh2's answer above, and rebooting a second time, the modules stay. So, I think this package was the problem. There are other modules that seem to not be missing anymore, so I think maybe it just needed a second reboot. Or maybe the `update-initramfs` was necessary.. that makes some sense.